# throw new InvalidArgumentException("Route [{$name}] not defined."); routing error in laravell 5.6

Tags: routes, laravel-5.6

I want to update my database and trying to redirect it to a defined url in Laravel 5.6

```
 public function update(Request $request, Apply1 $Apply1)
    {

    $Apply1 ->Given_Name=$request->Given_Name;
          $Apply1 ->Surname=$request->Surname;
          $Apply1 ->Date_Birth=$request->Date_Birth;
          $Apply1 ->Place_Birth=$request->Place_Birth;
          $Apply1 ->Mother_Name=$request->Mother_Name;
          $Apply1 ->Father_Name=$request->Father_Name;
          $Apply1 ->Passport_Number=$request->Passport_Number;
          $Apply1 ->Passport_Issue_Date=$request->Passport_Issue_Date;
          $Apply1 ->Passport_Expiry_Date=$request->Passport_Expiry_Date;
          $Apply1 ->Type_Supporting_Doc=$request->Supporting_Doc;
          $Apply1 ->Supporting_Doc_Form=$request->city;
          $Apply1 ->Supp_Doc_Expiry_Date=$request->Supp_Expiry_Date;
          $Apply1 ->E_mail_address=$request->mail_address;
          $Apply1 ->Phone_Number=$request->Phone_Number; 
          $Apply1 ->Address=$request->Address;
          $Apply1 ->City=$request->Permanent_City;
          $Apply1 ->State=$request->Address;
          $Apply1 ->Postal_Code=$request->Permanent_City;
          $Apply1 ->save();   

         return redirect(Route('Apply1.show1', $Apply1->id));         

  }
```

and my defined route is in web.php file is

```
Route::get('Apply1/show1/{id}', function ($id) {
   return 'User '.$id;
});
```

but still getting error in the end that ("Route [{$name}] not defined.");
i have defined the correct route but i don,t know why i am getting this error again

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are not following the [named route documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#named-routes) properly.

Your route:

```
Route::get('Apply1/show1/{id}', function ($id) {
   return 'User '.$id;
});
```

According to the documentation, you need to add `name` at the end of the route. That means, you should add it like this..

```
Route::get('Apply1/show1/{id}', function ($id) {
   return 'User '.$id;
})->name('Apply1.show1'); // you had not written this
```

In this way, you will get your desired result.